# Exception while deploying to JBoss 7.1.1, caused by: org.springframework:main is not found in local module

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, grails-2.0

I'm trying to implement module for my grails application, which is using Spring Security. Since the Spring Security and Grails are having large number of dependencies, the war size becomes more than 80MB. In order to avoid this, I'm trying to access these dependency from the module.

But, I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy the grails WAR in jboss 7.1.1.Final.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.IFP.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.IFP.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.IFP.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.springframework:main is not found in local module loader @1f88953 (roots: C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1207)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>      
            <module name="com.sits.grails">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF**"/>
                    <include path="org**"/>
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.sits.grails">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
        .........
        .........
        <resource-root path="jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsr166y-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="netty-all-4.0.15.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="rhino-1.7R4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="serializer-2.7.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="sitemesh-2.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-aspects-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-context-support-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-expression-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.50.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="tomcat-jdbc-7.0.50.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="tomcat-juli-7.0.50.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar"/>        
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="sun.jdk"/>
       <module name="org.javassist" optional="true"/>
       <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
       <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>     
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

In my MANIFEST.MF file have the dependencies declared

```
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j,com.sits.grails,org.springframework
```

I'm not understanding what causes this issue. If anyone can help me to identify will be a great help. Thanks.

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
            <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The module names specified in MANIFEST.MF are not package names but module names as define in the module.xml in JBoss

Your module.xml which contains spring jar is named as com.sits.grails.Hence your MANIFEST.MF should not include org.springframework as its not defined as a separate module.

Comment: I removed the org.springframework from the MANIFEST.MF. Now i'm getting the following error.'ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'

Comment: Now the spring jars are accessible. The exception might be due to your config. May you show the configuration with the pluginManager bean

Comment: Did you mean the **ApplicationContext.xml** file or the configurations in the **Config.groovy** file.

Comment: I have updated my post with the **ApplicationContext.xml** file. Please refer.